# Where can I get sha1hexfltr?

Tags: windows-server-2012, g-suite

I just set up a new Windows Server 2012 domain controller and remembered I should install sha1hexfltr to allow my passwords to be uploaded to Google Apps via Google Apps Directory Sync. However, when I went to https://code.google.com/p/sha1hexfltr/ I get a page not found message. Does anyone know what happend to this project? Is this no longer needed with the latest versions of GADS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that Google has written their own solution [Google Apps Password Sync](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2611859&topic=2611858&ctx=topic). It automatically sends passwords to Google as they change, instead of storing them in Active Directory for GADS to upload later. The configuration instructions are available [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2611842). You will need to install and configure this app on each writable domain controller

For those of you migrating from sha1hexfltr, here are the steps to remove it.

1. Remove C:\windows\System32\sha1hexfltr.dll
2. Open regedit and remove the "sha1hexfltr" line from HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\Notification Packages
3. Reboot your server
4. Don't forget to update your GADS configuration so it doesn't sync user passwords with the division attribute anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking this (http://code.google.com/r/9416269-sha1hexfltr/source/checkout). It seems that the repository was cloned to another location.

For further information you can look current GADS documentation (http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2611842&topic=2611858&ctx=topic).

Answer (score 2):

There is a newer filter DLL available here:
http://code.google.com/p/hashing-password-filter/

Full installation details [here](http://code.google.com/p/hashing-password-filter/wiki/Installation):

This will do the same job that sha1hexfltr did, catching password change events to create hashes that are compatible with Google Apps.